# Magento 2.3.3 newsletter subscription not working

Tags: magento2.3.3, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I am having issues with the newsletter subscription in magento 2.3.3-p1 (never set it up in any other version).
I have created the transaction email templates and selected them in Configuration > Customer > Newsletter and made sure this is set to enabled. I have "confirm subscription" enabled but i dont get the confirmation email or a success message on the website. I am using the Mageplaza SMTP plugin and i have tested this and it does work.
I am using Porto theme and it is the signup box in the footer that i have tried. On account sign up, ticking the box to subscribe works.
Where do i need to look next?

Comment: Please mention proper issue

Comment: I did. "i dont get the confirmation email or a success message on the website". The subscription does not happen

Comment: what's showing error in click to subscription button

Comment: There isnt an error, i click the button and the page reloads but no email sends and the email address is not added to the subscription list

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I have the same issue